# Adjust width of a gantt chart

Tags: pgfgantt, charts

The chart produced by below code is too wide. How can I make it small enough to fit the page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
            %today=15,%
            %today offset=.5,%
            %today label=Heute,%
            %progress=today,%
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
            progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
            ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, if you want colours and infographics, using something else is probably wise. Why torture and twist that isn't designed to do that into doing that?  You can always import graphics and PDFs into a *TeX file later on....

Comment: You don't use any sectional mark-up. And if your question only concerns the last bit, why post the first bit and the middle bit? But, in any case, as it stands, your question is extremely unclear and does not address a general issue. You are rather asking other people to provide a design service. And, apart from the service part, this is not a site about design anyway.

Comment: While I appreciate your enthusiasm, a phd research proposal is simply nonsense to everyone other than the freshest phd students . Spend your time and energy on a thesis template and use simple excel to make the table if your institution wants one. For example put infinity symbols next to `literature review` and `purchase equipment`.

Comment: @MickyK rather it's the other way round, the question is waiting for you to edit it to bring it back on topic for this site, The body of the question should be asking a specific question about tex, If you want to make the gantt chart package do a specific detail make a small example and ask about _that_ . General design issues for the document are just too general.

Comment: @MickyK your question is just "make this for me" Personally I wouldn't vote to re-open in this form.  The question should be more like "this code (for a 4 line, not 40 line) gantt chart produces the following output, but I want to colour bar 2 blue and add an arrow between the first two blocks" Perhaps you will get enough people to vote to re-open, but if not, take the above as friendly advice on how to make it possible for people to help.

Comment: @MickyK No: it's still entirely unclear what you want to know.

Comment: @MickyK "Need Guidance" is not a question. Please read the comments above that were trying to help you.

Comment: The code added is just a sample of a Gantt chart in LaTeX, not a real MWE you have problems in.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I want to make same chart which show in given figure

Comment: The proper way to ask questions is that you should work on the thing you want and make a MWE which is not just a sample that everybody can find over the net. It is part of your work in which you have problems. Also, that type of "write latex code of this figure for me" is not really accepted in this community. Just look at this question on meta and you will better understand how this website works: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Didn't we just reopen the question to show the OP that he is on the right track? Though there might be some information missing, i don't see the point in closing a question within two hours of re-opening.

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree. On the other hand, I don't think it should have been re-opened. I have no clue what is being asked.

Comment: @Johannes_B (and @cfr) I've voted for reopen too, but in the meantime I regret this. But I won't vote for close now

Comment: @MickyK Rather than putting your energies into adding incorrect tags to your question and making trivial edits to its title, you could spend them attempting to construct the diagram you want. Best case scenario: your question is no longer relevant as you find the answer yourself. Worst case scenario: you make a start but you hit an obstacle you can't overcome fairly early on. Then you have an MWE which you can use to replace the code in the question and make it something people really can answer. You'll also have a nice, specific problem to ask about.

Comment: In the meantime, this question has been asked over at [LaTeX-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=26530&p=90868#p90863).

Comment: @MickyK No problem with cross-posts. They should just have a link to each other to prevent double work. Johannes added the link, thanks. Perhaps your idea to switch to a discussion forum is good, if a question cannot be clearly stated but a support discussion would go on (which is not the format here on the site).

Comment: Isn't that code just the example you had before plus a lot of irrelevant bits? Looks very like where this question started to me. Note again that **you should not load `epsfig`**. Also, you should tidy up the preamble to avoid loading packages multiple times. This is still a 'draw this for me' and really quite unclear. I would not vote to reopen the question in its current form.

Comment: You've got a response on LaTeX-community asking you to clarify what you want help with. The same question applies here.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would think that your question is about how to fit four years of the chart on a page. If that is really the case, *why haven't you just said so*?  If that isn't the problem, can you please describe *precisely* what is, rather than saying "I think you'll understand"? What is blindingly obvious to you, may be the exact opposite for us.

Comment: @Yes, how to fit four years of the chart on a page.

Comment: Right. Then it would be helpful if you edited your question to include that information. At the same time, you might as well remove all the code that isn't related to the Gantt chart. If you had posted the code generating a chart with all four years, and just said something like "the chart is too wide for the page, how can I make it small enough to fit", this would likely have been answered a long time ago.

Comment: The documentclass and page margins is actually useful information, `standalone` will always make the page large enough ...

Comment: In order to make the chart fit on a page of size "Letter" or "A4 you'll need to use an absurdly small font size. Thus, you should really contemplate printing the chart on a sheet of paper that's at least A3-sized (and possibly even larger).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok then what could I used

Comment: What you had was `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, if that is what you intend to use for your final document, then use that in your question as well.

Comment: @MickyK - Of course it's "still [the] same issue": depending on your TeX distribution, your document's default paper size will be either "US Letter" (8.5" x 11") or "A4". There's simply no way the massive gantt chart is going to fit on such a piece of paper, even if you set the document margins to zero, unless you choose an aburdly small font size (and make the document illegible). You need to figure out what the largest piece of paper is that your printer can handle -- and dimension the document accordingly.

Comment: Of course, my point was that to know how much the chart should be shrinked, we need to know the size we have to work with.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Assuming the OP is working with either "Letter" or "A4" paper and has set the page margins to 1 inch or so, the shrinkage factor will have to be 50% or more in order to make the chart fit within the text block -- making the output illegible unless a free magnifying glass is distributed with each copy of the document. Hence my strong recommendation to start working with a (much!) larger paper size...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. If i rotate the chart, then it is possible to fit the chart on "A4" Paper size

Comment: @MickyK - Are you sure about this claim? Using a page size of A4, I tried rotating your chart 90 degrees, and I couldn't make it fit in the text block because the chart has too many rows.

Comment: @Mico Sure, I see that problem. My comment still applies. And the row height can be adjusted.

Comment: @Mico Yea I am sure using a page size of A4. But I can't try the rotating command

Comment: @MickyK - I wasn't challenging the assertion that you're using A4-sized paper. I was questioning the claim that rotating the chart by 90 degrees will let the charge fit on an A4-sized sheet of paper -- absent the use of some absurdly small font, and absent some adjustments to the y-axis parameters you haven't let us in on so far.

Comment: @Mico It could of course be that he didn't let us in on those parameters because he wasn't aware of them ...  Surely that is no crime.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it is possible to make it fancy

Comment: Was that a question? If yes, define "fancy".

Comment: @TorbjørnT. colorful and different style

Comment: There are a few examples in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf), I suggest you scroll through that and see if you can find something like what you're after. If that doesn't work, I would suggest that you create a new question. If you can, try to describe more precisely what kind of style you want, it's makes it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. How to have the title at the top of the gantt chart

Comment: @MickyK You can create more than one question/thread about the same chart you know. The question of how to move the title is quite different from the question of how to change the size, so I urge you to click *Ask question* instead of *Add comment*. It also increases your chances of getting an answer, as more people will see your question. I don't even know what title you mean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are two suggestions. The first one uses a rather small font size to make the chart fit within the margins of a standard `article`. I've also set the labels in fixed width nodes, so that text is broken over two lines. Finally, the `x unit`, `y unit chart` and `y unit title` are modified.

In  the second option I've set the chart on a landscape page with smaller margins, and reduced the `y unit chart` and `y unit title` a bit from their default of `1cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text, remove in your own document

\usepackage{geometry} % to change margins
\usepackage{pdflscape} % provides the landscape environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \RaggedLeft

\begin{document}

% First option
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
            %today=15,%
            %today offset=.5,%
            %today label=Heute,%
            %progress=today,%
            x unit=0.3cm,
            y unit title=0.7cm,
            y unit chart=0.8cm,
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
            progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%},
            milestone label font=\tiny,
            group label font=\tiny,
            title label font=\tiny,
            bar label node/.style={text width=3cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east},
            milestone label node/.style={text width=2cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east},
            group label node/.style={text width=3cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east}
            ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}


% Second option
\newgeometry{vmargin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
            %today=15,%
            %today offset=.5,%
            %today label=Heute,%
            %progress=today,%
            y unit title=0.7cm,
            y unit chart=0.6cm,
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
            progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
            ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: WooooooooW Great

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to define the option `expand chart=\textwidth` when you create the Gantt chart. This will ensure that the chart width will be equal to the text width. See an example below in which I show the full code.

```latex
\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
    x unit=0.7cm,
    y unit title=0.6cm,
    y unit chart=0.6cm,
    title/.append style={fill=gray!20},
    title label font=\bfseries,
    title height=1,
    bar height=0.6,
    bar/.append style={fill},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=blue!50},
    bar/.append style={fill=red!50},
    progress label text={},
    milestone label font=\bfseries\small,
    milestone height=0.8,
    milestone top shift=0.2,
    milestone/.append style={fill=red},
    group/.append style={draw=black, fill=green!30},
    group height=.3,
    group peaks height=.2,
    group label font=\bfseries\small,
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group top shift=.3,
    group height=.2,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group peaks width=0.2,
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=gray!50},
    link/.style={->,thick},
    expand chart=\textwidth,
    today=6,
    progress=today,
    % inline
    ]{1}{17}

    \gantttitle{Plan for Writing a Scientific Paper}{17} \\
    \gantttitle{Week}{17} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,17}{1} \\

    \ganttgroup{Research}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttbar{Literature review}{1}{4} \\

    \ganttgroup{Experiment}{5}{10} \\
    \ganttbar{Define methodology}{5}{5} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Data collection}{6}{7} \\
    \ganttbar{Data analysis}{8}{10} \\

    \ganttgroup{Writing}{11}{16} \\
    \ganttbar{Introduction}{11}{13} \\
    \ganttbar{Methodology}{12}{13} \\
    \ganttbar{Results and Discussion}{14}{15} \\
    \ganttbar{Conclusion}{16}{16} \\

    \ganttmilestone{Submission}{17} \\

\end{ganttchart}
```

[image]